# I created a library and was wondering if the design is inefficient

Tags: c++, c++11

In the design of my library I construct a lot of objects and was wondering if this will cause it to be inefficient.

I created a library the creates and runs a query. The query is a class that takes an rvalue reference to a `initializer_list` of `Bind` objects. Each `Bind` takes some value.

I'm thinking that the design is inefficient because each `Bind` object is going to be making a copy of its value except for strings if we use `const char*`s. On top of that we have to construct an entire `Bind` object for each of those values. I then round all the `Bind`s up into an `initializer_list` and move them into a `vector` which I'm not sure how much overhead there is there. This is created in the `Query` object which might not be that expensive to construct and only one `Query` object is created.

Looking at the `main` function at the bottom of the code snippet might be all you need to look at.

```
class Database {
public:
    Database() = default;
    ~Database() = default;
    Result run(Query&& query);    
};

class Query {
public:
    Query(const char* query, std::initializer_list<Bind>&& binds);
    ~Query() = default;

    ...

private:
    std::string m_query;
    std::vector<Bind> m_binds;
};

Query::Query(const char* query, std::initializer_list<Bind>&& binds) : m_query(query), m_binds(binds) {}


class Bind {
    friend Query;
public:
    explicit Bind(int32_t i);
    explicit Bind(int64_t i);
    explicit Bind(uint32_t i);
    explicit Bind(float f);
    explicit Bind(const char* str);

private:
    int bind(sqlite3_stmt* stmt, int column);

    ColumnType m_type;
    union {
        int64_t m_i;
        float m_f;
        const char* m_str;
    };
    size_t m_str_size;
};

int main()
{
    Database db;
    auto result = db.run(Query(
        "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        Bind(id),
        Bind(first_name),
        Bind(last_name),
        Bind(age),
        Bind(height),
        Bind(weight),
        Bind(siblings),
        Bind(hometown),
        Bind(mom),
        Bind(dad),
        Bind(num_pets),
        Bind(os::time_since_epoch()),
        Bind(location),
        Bind(json),
    }));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you have code that works and you believe it can be made to work better, you should ask at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). In general Stack Overflow is better at fixing code and Code Review is better at improving code.

Comment: My experience: 1) Get things working, keeping code as closest as possible to the concept in mind. 2) Test and debug to ensure it does what it's supposed to. 3) Make tests with real load and check whether performance is acceptable. If the last one fails THEN start to think about optimization. Optimization usually causes extra effort (-> costs) now and later because it makes code harder to read and maintain. Btw. I cannot imagine something less harmless than to copy some integrals... ;-)

Comment: And, maybe, this should be kept in mind as well: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/). ;-)

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the reference. I had no clue that existed.

Comment: @Scheff That makes a lot of sense. I think I'll continue developing the library and capture performance metrics later on to see if optimization is required.

Comment: @Scheff And I'm using sqlite3 which does all the sanitation when using the bind interface so I should be covered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally `std::initializer_list<T>` is just a couple pointers. These is nothing to move there. So taking it by `&&` doesn't make much sense. The standard library takes it by value, and I suggest you do it the same way. There is nothing to move in `Bind` either.

If all `Bind` constructors have only one parameter, you can make a variadic constructor and construct each `Bind` in-place with `emplace_back()`:

```
class Query {
public:
    template<class... Bind_args>
    Query(const char* query, Bind_args&&... bind_args) {
        m_binds.reserve(sizeof...(Bind_args));
        (m_binds.emplace_back(std::forward<Bind_args>(bind_args)), ...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Bind> m_binds;
};
```

This will simplify `Query` construction to

```
query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 1, "33", 2.f);
```

Whether it will be more efficient is hard to tell without profiling. Nowadays compilers (and linkers) can be really good at code optimization, all this overhead you describe might be optimized out completely.

If C++17 with fold expressions is not available, you can replace the fold-expression with C++11 version:

```
int sink[] = {(m_binds.emplace_back(std::forward<Bind_args>(bind_args)), 0)...};
(void)sink;
```

---

> The `Bind` interface needs to support multiple arguments

Then these arguments can be packed into tuples:

```
class Query {
public:
    template<class... Tuples>
    Query(const char* query, Tuples&&... bind_arg_tuples) {
        m_binds.reserve(sizeof...(Tuples));
        (emplace_from_tuple(std::forward<Tuples>(bind_arg_tuples)), ...);
    }

private:
    template<class Tuple>
    void emplace_from_tuple(Tuple&& arg_tuple) {
        emplace_from_tuple(std::forward<Tuple>(arg_tuple), 
            std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>{});
    }

    template<class Tuple, std::size_t... is>
    void emplace_from_tuple(Tuple&& arg_tuple, std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        m_binds.emplace_back(std::get<is>(std::forward<Tuple>(arg_tuple))...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Bind> m_binds;
};

query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", 
    std::tuple(1, 2), std::tuple("33", "44"), std::tuple(2.f, 3.f));
```

This code avoids calling copy constructors of `Bind` and correctly moves all arguments (including movable-only types like `std::unique_ptr`). But for lightweight `Bind` object this is likely to be an unnecessary over-complication.

Comment: I like your suggestion however the `Bind` interface needs to support multiple arguments if the user wants to use sqlite3 column names or specify the column index.

Comment: @rangeme, in fact, this is the same as taking `initializer_list`... To avoid copy construction, arguments can be packed in a `std::tuple`, and then the same variadic pack method can be used. I'll add into an answer, but I doubt it will be more efficient after compiler optimizes code.